# Ethereum network on TCP vs QUIC protocol (UDP-based) on data transferring

Tags: go-ethereum, network, devp2p, p2p

I'm new to the Geth p2p network (devp2p). Devp2p uses both TCP and UDP to run it's networking protocol. The TCP is for the data transferring between each node and the UDP is for nodes discovery. I would like to know if it possible to use the QUIC protocol (a UDP-based protocol) for data transferring instead of TCP. I've heard that QUIC brings the better performance compared to TCP. Are there any concerns that make Geth and many other blockchain nodes still using TCP?